# Does the force that need to be applied to pull the weight out of a well by string is more at the start?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, gravity, drag

One way to estimate depth of the well is attaching a weight to a string then throwing it into the well until it touch a hard surface then pulling the string out of the well and evaluate its length.

Assuming there is no water in a well, I'm wondering, is it true that the person who pulls the string to take the weight out, should apply more force at the start (when the weight is almost at the bottom of the well) than at the end of process? I had done this process before and I felt at the start I had to apply more force. Since $W=mg$ is approximately constant, is this extra needed force come from air resistance or there exist other important factors too? (I assumed the string is very light and its mass is negligible and the weight that moves upward doesn't have friction with the wall of the well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your experience is very subjective, so to evaluate the scenario you really ought to conduct a more controlled experiment. However, there are several factors potentially at work as follows...

When you first start to raise the object you have to accelerate it to get it moving; thereafter you only need to maintain its speed, so the force required is less.

You have assumed that the mass of the string is negligible, but in reality it might not be- your muscles might very well notice the difference between raising a long length of string and a short one.

Once the weight is moving at a constant speed, air resistance will not vary appreciably between the bottom and the top of the well.

You might unconsciously change the position of your body and arms between the start of the exercise and the end, which might cause an actual or perceived difference in the effect involved.